# Add variables conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` package and want to create variable only if condition exists. The function below performs recoding and works fine. I want this line of code `!!var := ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(!!var)), 0, !!var)` run only if the variable has missing values. I also need to check whether the variable name is valid or not.

```
recoding <- function(df, var, interval) {
  var  <- enquo(var)
  var2 <- paste0(as_label(var), '_group')

  df <-  df %>% mutate(
    !!var := ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(!!var)), 0, !!var),
    !!var2 := Hmisc::cut2(!!var, cuts = interval)
  )

  message(var2, " variable has been created")
  return(df)
}

mtcars %>% recoding(mpg, c(0,20,50,Inf))
```

Comment: You can add a `if/else` statement by checking `sum(is.na(!!var)) > 0`

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized - it will check every element of a vector, and return a vector of the same length. This is a *control flow* need, so you want `if(){}else{}` not `ifelse()`, with code like in  akrun's comment.

Comment: If else{} can't work under mutate()?

Comment: You would wrap the `mutate` in `if()`. `if(anyNA(df[, var]) {df <- df %>% mutate...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering here, as this will be too long for a comment.

I think I understand why you want to run the `ifelse` line only when there is NAs in the variable, to save time/resources. But it will be an overhead. You will be testing for NAs in the variable **twice**, first to check if there are any NAs, and after that to check which are NA to change them.

```
# lets check if the var has NAs (as per @akrun and @Gregor comments)
if (sum(is.na(!!var)) > 0) { # just now you just check all the var values to see if there is NAs
  df <-  df %>% mutate(
    !!var := ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(!!var)), 0, !!var), # And here you are checking again  
    !!var2 := Hmisc::cut2(!!var, cuts = interval)
  )
}
```

The code as it is is perfect. You only check it once and if there are any NA the change will be done. If not, the variable will be the same. I know it's counterintuitive, but trying to perform the operation only in NAs-containing variables will not save you time or resources, in fact it will "double" them.

About the var name checking, try

```
  # checking if var is valid
  if (!as_label(var) %in% names(df)) {
    stop(as_label(var), ' is not present in df')
  }
```

just before the the data frame modification step. That way the function will throw and error if the variable var is nor in the data frame.